# IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9 // python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot a matrix in python and my code is like,

```
def myplot(data, playerlist = Players):
for name in playerlist:
    plt.plot(data[Pdict[name]], label=name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
plt.xticks(list(range(0,10)), Seasons, rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

though it gets plotted but i get an error like,

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 myplot(FreeThrowAttempts)

```
<ipython-input-32-8341070ea579> in myplot(data, playerlist)
      1 def myplot(data, playerlist = Players):
      2     for name in playerlist:
 ----> 3         plt.plot(data[Pdict[name]], label=name)
      4     plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
      5     plt.xticks(list(range(0,10)), Seasons, rotation='vertical')

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9
```

I am not sure how to solve this error, can someone please help me to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please fix your indentation. And this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might want to read the linked content and edit your question to get good answers.

Comment: Thanks Mr.T I will Keep that in mind.

Comment: Apart from saying you are trying to access an element of a list that isn't there, this cannot be properly answered without a [mcve].